# Why am I getting these no suitable method found errors?

Tags: java

Im trying to write this class copied from my textbook. From what i understand, I copied the code exactly as it appeared, with minor changes to variable names. But when I do anything, the two lines `number = getInt(Sc3, prompt);` and `d = getDouble(sc3, prompt);` throw errors that say "no suitable method found for  `getInt/getDouble(Scanner, String)`. Why is this and what can I code to fix this? The surrounding code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Console {

   private static Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static String getString(String prompt) {
      System.out.print(prompt);
      String s = sc3.next();
      sc3.nextLine();
      return s;
   }

   public static int getInt(String prompt) {
      int number = 0;
      boolean isValid = false;
      while (isValid) {
         System.out.print(prompt);
         if (sc3.hasNextInt()) {
            number = sc3.nextInt();
            isValid = true;
         }else {
            System.out.println("Error! Entry must be an integer. Please try again.");
         }
         sc3.nextLine();
      }
      return number;
   }

   public static int getInt(String prompt, int minimum, int maximum) {
      int number = 0;
      boolean isValid = false;
      while (!isValid) {
         number = getInt(sc3, prompt);
         if (number <= minimum) {
            System.out.println("Error. User entry nust be greater than" + " " + minimum + " " + ".");
         } else if (number >= maximum) {
            System.out.println("Error. User entry must be less than" + " " + maximum + " " + ".");
         } else {
            isValid = true;
         }
      }
      return number;
   }

   public static double getDouble(String prompt) {
      double d = 0;
      boolean isValid = false;
      while (!isValid) {
         System.out.print(prompt);
         if (sc3.hasNextDouble()) {
            d = sc3.nextDouble();
            isValid = true;
         } else {
            System.out.println("Error. Invalid number. Try again.");
         }
         sc3.nextLine();
      }
      return d;
   }

   public static double getDouble(String prompt, double minimum, double maximum) {
      double d = 0;
      boolean isValid = false;
      while (!isValid) {
         d = getDouble(sc3, prompt);
         if (d <= minimum) {
            System.out.println("Error. Number must be greater than" + minimum + ".");
         }else if (d >= maximum) {
            System.out.println("Error. Number must be less than" + maximum + ".");
         }else {
            isValid = true;
         }
         return d;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You're getting the error because there are no methods called `getInt` or `getDouble` which each take a `Scanner` (which `sc3` is) and a `String` (which `prompt` is) as arguments.  There _are_, however, `getInt` and `getDouble` methods which take just a `String` argument; maybe you meant to write `getInt(prompt)` and `getDouble(prompt)` instead?

Comment: I fixed it but now Im getting a "reached end of file while parsing" error with the barckets at the end. It LOOKS like its fine, but it keeps saying its wrong when I try running it.

Comment: Can't just _look_ fine, gotta **be** fine (;->).  Check that all your brackets are correctly paired: it's easy to leave out a needed right-bracket or slip in an extra unwanted left-bracket.

Answer (score 0):

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have different parameter lists

from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

So you are missing the `getInt(Scanner Sc3, String prompt)` and `getDouble(Scanner sc3, String prompt)` methods.